# perl excel to pdf

Tags: perl, excel, file, pdf

I'm using perl with an excel template to try to make creating invoices for clients somewhat automated. My only issue is that I'd really like to be able to convert this excel file to a PDF when I'm done, but I can't seem to find any perl modules that do anything of the sort. Anyone ever heard of something like this being done? I know it can be done somehow, since word and open office manage to do it!

Comment: The question I always ask when people want to convert data to a printed format is: "what do you want it to look like"? Once you see that that question needs answering, you start to see the solutions. You need to format the data somehow and create a PDF from that via LaTeX or HTML or some other structured format.

Comment: The next problem is that working with closed systems makes this hard. Excel isn't meant to work with outside tools, the designers built it this way so that you would have to use other products within the same line. Can you use LibreOffice instead? I'm pretty sure that the tools exist to work with files in the opendocument formats.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply shell out to [unoconv](http://dag.wieers.com/home-made/unoconv/).

There are also [Perl bindings to UNO](http://sf.net/projects/perluno/), but last time I looked, they didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to convert/flatten the Excel file first, and then figure out a way to pipe it in, but this may get you headed in the right direction http://metacpan.org/pod/PDF::Create

Comment: what do you mean by convert/flatten the file? Is this something I can do with one of perl's excel modules?

Comment: If the excel file is text only you can parse it and export the excel to say CSV and then write the PDF by inputting the CSV data - otherwise depending on your operating system you could make use of the adobe pdf printer driver